# Translating "Ciudad de San Diego" (for Lyrical Purposes) Entirely into English

Tags: gramática, lingüística, música

When I was a student, I took many years of Spanish; however, I have since received conflicting information on the equivalence of the English name *James* and the Spanish name *Diego*.

In school, I was left with the impression that each is a translation of the other.

Since then, I have been given to understand otherwise; i.e., that "James" is not a proper translation of "Diego".

QUESTION: Does the name *Diego* translate into *James* (and visa-versa); and if so, would it be OK  to(in the lyrics for a musical piece) refer to ``Ciudad de San Diego'' as *City of Saint James* or
*Saint James city*? Would this be linguistically correct?

Note: Probably most everybody knows exactly the city meant when the words "San Diego" are uttered; but there is a reason why I want to use, if possible, the definite English translation of "Diego", if one exists.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El punto de partida para comenzar a responder debería ser el analizar por qué se identifican como homólogos a ambos nombres. Es evidente que la mayoría de las fuentes que busquemos coincidirán en que *Diego* es equivalente de *James* o de *Jacob*. Todas las razones están basadas en la etimología de ambos nombres:

> Diego has long been interpreted as variant of Tiago [...], an abbreviation of Santiago, from the older Sant Yago "Saint Jacob", in English known as Saint James [...] This has been the standard interpretation of the name since at least the 19th century... [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego)]

> As has been stated, “Diego” is originally a short form of Santiago, which represents Saint (Sant-) Jacob (-iago).
> [...] The progression was roughly: Iacob —Iacobus (with a Latin ending added)—Iacomus—Jacomus (I and J being at one time the same letter)—James. In other words, the Biblical character we know today as “Saint James” was originally “Saint Jacob,” and the Old Testament Jacob and New Testament James represent the same Hebrew name [...] [[Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-English-equivalent-of-the-name-Diego)]

Pero la misma Wikipedia nos contradice más adelante:

> In the later 20th century, the traditional identification of Diego = Jacobo [or James] came to be seen as untenable. [...] The name Didacus, while unattested in antiquity, predates the earliest record of the form Diego. The oldest record for Didacus according to Floriano (1949) dates to 747, with numerous further records during the 9th century... [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego)]

Por lo visto, no hay un consenso claro sobre la etimología. Incluso si nos remitiéramos a *Didacus*, no parece haber una evolución clara del nombre hacia el inglés tal como la hubo en el español. Asimismo, esto conlleva otro problema más grave: se estaría ignorando cuál es la percepción que un nativo angloparlante (o hispanoparlante) tiene sobre el nombre Diego. Y es que, si bien ninguno tendrá problema en reconocer que es hispano, difícilmente reconozcan alguna relacion entre los nombres mencionados.

Por lo tanto, ¿cuál sería la traducción más apropiada para Diego? *Diego*. Y te ofrezco dos argumentos para sostener esta conclusión. Por un lado, el uso de dicho nombre para las personas nacidas ha cobrado fuerza tanto en los [Estados Unidos](https://www.everything-birthday.com/name/m/diego) como en el [Reino Unido](https://www.ukbabynames.com/boys/diego). Por el otro, ya hay varios lugares que se llaman [*Saint James*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._James), otros tantos que se llaman [*Saint Jacob*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Jacob_(disambiguation)) y otros tantos que se llaman *San Diego*; y nadie (que use su sentido común) piensa en que los tres nombres sean intercambiables, ya sea en inglés o en castellano. Todo esto indica que, si dejamos de lado las discusiones etimológicas, hoy en día los nombres no se consideran equivalentes.

Por último, me interesaría saber cuál es la razón tan oscura que te lleva a *tener que* preguntar esto. ¿Para qué traducir? Actualmente la tendencia que se observa—aunque sea otra utopía más—es exactamente la opuesta: ya sea una ciudad o una persona, se procura respetar los *endónimos*, en lugar de inventar *exónimos* que sólo conlleven a generar más dudas de que efectivamente sean traducciones apropiadas de los nombres ‘auténticos’. ¿Querés hacer una rima o que te dé la métrica y es por eso que necesitás una traducción? Adelante, tenés licencia poética para hacerlo, nadie te va a juzgar. Incluso algunas veces los grandes artistas han tenido que recurrir a traducciones algo forzosas con fines estéticos. Pero no esperés que el que escuche la canción reconozca la ciudad a la que realmente tenías la intención de referirte.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su exhaustiva respuesta. La razón de mi pregunta es que deseo aludir en varios aspectos de la canción al santo concreto que da nombre a la ciudad, sin mencionar nunca "San Diego". La canción está escrita para oyentes de habla inglesa. Basándome en el contenido de la canción, cualquier oyente que haya estado allí debería saber que me estoy refiriendo a San Diego, U.S.A., sin que yo lo diga explícitamente, que es lo que quiero.

Comment: @I.Chekhov En mi opinión, si es con ese fin entonces es más que aceptable traducir el nombre como ‘James’ o ‘Jacob’

Comment: Muchas gracias! :)